# HTML5 Audio player resizes on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, html5-audio, audio-player

Straight forward HTML5 Audio player. Looks good on desktop but on mobile it gets a little weird. It keeps its width but repositions and floats over the element it's inside. How do I stop it from repositioning on mobile devices?

Hope you can see the yellow border for reference.

**Desktop printscreen:**

[image]

**Mobile printscreen:**

[image]

When you zoom on the mobile device, the player starts moving towards its intended position (and player controls appear) - the more you zoom, the more it moves upwards, until halting in the middle of the element:

**Mobile zoomed printscreen:**

[image]

Been trying all the `position` values and done a fair share of googling. I don't understand what causes this, so I don't know where to start trying to solve it. Hope someone can help.

HTML:

```
<div id="audiowrap">
  <audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio
  </audio>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
audio { margin:0 0 0 5px; width:540px; }
#audiowrap {
  margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code that determines how you switch between the mobile and desktop player? Also it's not exactly clear as to what you're trying to achieve? Stop the player from repositioning? Are those icons not supposed to appear in mobile version, or what's the issue here?

Comment: Thought it was clearly implied in the entirety of my post that I didn't want it to reposition, so felt that it was over excessive to literally state it. But I understand it can be very confusing if you remove each single sentence from its context. Should have known better when posting here, I guess. I don't use any code to switch, I just upload it to ftp and watch it from my mobile.

Comment: My point is, it's impossible for us to tell without at least a replicable part of the source code. Issues like these are usually caused by elements overlapping and auto spacing. You can enforce an element's position using the position: relative; property and then spacing it with top/bottom/left/right. But that's the best answer I can give you without source code.

Comment: Alright, didn't think it was necessary since it's basically just <audio> inside a div that I made to show that it's repositioning on mobile. However, I've added it.

Comment: What browser were you seeing this in?

Comment: Browser? Device? Can't reproduce this on my Android device with Chrome, it behaves correctly... May be some weird browser/device specific bug, but I don't know

Comment: I'm checking in both safari and chrome from iPhone. Glad to hear it works on Android at least xD

Answer (score 0):

Currently when I check this on iPhone X, it is overflowing the container with a space at the top.

Remove the width and the overlap at the bottom will disappear

https://jsfiddle.net/yqgx97p1/9/

```
audio {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

It's a bit difficult to debug this on a real device but if you have the cables, you can connect your device to your computer and debug/test much easier. From what I can tell, the player itself has a set height (background red) and some weird default styles that possibly could be overridden but you would need to inspect on a computer to figure it out

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, unless someone is sitting on the styles that gets adeed(?) when it hits a mobile device - I guess the safest bet is to remove width of player on mobile site?

Comment: You can remove the width and test it to see if you like the result but to get to the bottom of this you would need to connect your device to a computer so you can inspect the page to see if it is possible to make it work just like desktop

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as the HTML5 audio player on mobile and tablet was quite tall. The solution that worked in my case was simply to set `.player{height=40px;}`.

This solved my issue of having extremely large players on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="audiowrap">
  <audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio
  </audio>http://162.210.197.146:9423/
</div>`enter code here`
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. We appreciate answering questions - old or new, but please make sure you are referring to the actual issue described in the original post, and explain how and why your suggestion would solve it.